# How to run Graticule labels in OpenLayers 3?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, label, openlayers-3

I need to run Graticule **labels** in **OpenLayers 3**. I want to show and style labels of graticule with angle units. I just found this :

https://github.com/Brictarus/ol3/blob/d41eb87204e76cbf99d61915eb89b1c16c4a4e05/examples/graticule.js

But I cant get it works in my html :

```
var polohaMysky = new ol.control.MousePosition({
  coordinateFormat: ol.coordinate.createStringXY(4),
  //projection: "EPSG:4326",
  className: "suradnice",
  target: document.getElementById("suradnice_div"),
                undefinedHTML: '0000'
})
            //------//
            var mierka = new ol.control.ScaleLine();
            var nahlad = new ol.control.OverviewMap();
            var a1 = new ol.source.OSM();
      var map = new ol.Map({
        renderer: 'canvas',
          // Zobrazenie súradníc myšky
        controls: ol.control.defaults({
            attributions: false
        }).extend([polohaMysky, mierka, nahlad]),
        layers: [
          new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: a1
          })
        ],
        target: 'map',
        view: new ol.View({
            //projection: 'EPSG:4326',
            center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([4.8, 47.75]),
          zoom: 3
        })
      });
           var lonFormatter = function(lon) {
  var formattedLon = Math.abs(Math.round(lon * 100) / 100);
  formattedLon += (lon < 0) ? 'W' : ((lon > 0) ? 'E' : '');
  return formattedLon;
};

var latFormatter = function(lat) {
  var formattedLat = Math.abs(Math.round(lat * 100) / 100);
  formattedLat += (lat < 0) ? 'S' : ((lat > 0) ? 'N' : '');
  return formattedLat;
};

// Create the graticule component
var graticule = new ol.Graticule({
  // the style to use for the lines, optional.
  strokeStyle: new ol.style.Stroke({
    color: 'rgba(255,120,0,0.9)',
    width: 2,
    lineDash: [0.5, 4]
  }),
  showLabels: true,
  lonLabelFormatter: lonFormatter,
  lonLabelPosition: 0.05,
  latLabelFormatter: latFormatter,
  latLabelPosition: 0.95
});
graticule.setMap(map);
```

When i run this code i just see only graticule without labels. Have you any idea what is wrong ? **Thanks for any help**.

Comment: That pull request is not merged to OL. So it won't work without modifying ol.js. See full change log and try to merge all the changes to ol.js and it may work. https://github.com/Brictarus/ol3/commit/d41eb87204e76cbf99d61915eb89b1c16c4a4e05

Comment: I add/load that changed olx.js and graticule.js from that link on the head but it dont work, labels nowhere.

Answer (score 0):

From [latest document](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.Graticule.html) , seems like OL3 is not support label yet

Answer (score 0):

Graticule labels are **not supported in OpenLayers 3** (latest version of OL3 is 3.20.1). See OL3 API reference here: https://openlayers.org/en/v3.20.1/apidoc/ol.Graticule.html

If you need to display graticule labels consider upgrading to OpenLayers 5, which does support graticule labels. See OL5 API reference here: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_Graticule.html